# set_by_lua & os.getenv within openresty:alpine docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, lua, docker-compose, openresty

I'm running `openresty` nginx within [official](https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty/) `alpine-fat` docker image, and openresty process starts with `nobody` user.

I need to set nginx variable with the next string:

```
set_by_lua $var 'return os.getenv("ENV_VAR")';
```

`docker-compose.yml` contains the next block:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.nginx
environment:
  - ENV_VAR=value
```

But, nginx worker process seems not getting its value, and `$var` remains empty.

I tried to add `export ENV_VAR=value` to `/etc/profile` file, but no use.
I tried to run openresty with `nginx` user, but it also can't see the value of `ENV_VAR` variable.

How can I make that thing work, if I can?

Comment: Try adding `env ENV_VAR;` to your nginx config. By default nginx will discard all environment variables, this will allow to save it.

Comment: u'r my lifesaver, mate, thank you, add this as an answer, please.

Comment: @cardinal-gray, is this working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `env ENV_VAR;` to your nginx config. By default nginx will discard all environment variables, this will allow to save it.

From https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env

> Syntax:   env variable[=value];
>
> Default:
>
> env TZ;
>
> Context:  main
>
> By default, nginx removes all environment variables inherited from its parent process except the TZ variable. This directive allows preserving some of the inherited variables, changing their values, or creating new environment variables.